# Переход по кнопке без ссылки на HTML странице средствами Java

Tags: java, ссылки, httpurlconnection

Хочу написать простой парсер с возможностью "перехода" по ссылкам страницы. 
То есть изначально у нас имеется главная страница какого-то сайта. Необходимо по меню перейти на другую страницу, а оттуда еще на другую. 
Проблем не возникает, если в дереве страницы на элементе висит `href`, но в некоторых случая кнопки сайта не подвешены к каким то ссылкам, а их url мы можем получить только путем разбирания тела запроса уже ПОСЛЕ нажатия на кнопку. (Пример подобной кнопки на скрине ниже[image: скрине]).

То есть, пока мы не нажмем на нее, мы не знаем, что за ссылка к ней прикреплена:[image: ссылка]

Есть ли возможность каким-то образом перейти с первой картинки на вторую путем "имитации" нажатия на кнопку с помощью Java? Интересует не просто "кликатель" по вкладкам, а именно бэкэнд из разряда `URLConnection` и прочими средствами установки соединения.

P.S. Да, я вижу закономерность id_session кнопки и ссылки, по которой мы переходим. Но это лишь конкретный пример и не везде так. Я бы хотел узнать общее решение.

Comment: По мне, так это вам нужно сидеть и изучать JS,HTML и всё, что касается относительно нужного вам сайта. Я однажды писал crawler, но у меня сайт был четко структурирован. Необходимо было  по тегам бегать, но это легко решалось через regexp, но в вашем случае...

Comment: @Dred, дело в том, что вы говорите о каком-то конкретном сайте, а я же наоборот хочу универсальный инструмент. Да, если есть что-то, что решает проблему эту в JS - тоже подойдет. Просто на данном этапе имею дело с Java и опыта с JS нет.

Comment: Да, я про то и говорю, что для какого-то конкретного сайта можно заморочиться, если вам это действительно нужно. Обычно "открытые" сайты/ресурсы предоставляют API. В данном случае, получается, что вы хотите "взломать" все сайты. Универсальности не получится, так как у кого-то "click()" открыт, у кого-то спрятан за ajax, у третьих вообще, на Java написано :D Так что, не реализуемо. Пусть меня поправят, если я не прав